# Getting Service cannot be resolved to a type error while consuming OSGi service

Tags: compiler-errors, adobe, aem, osgi-bundle

I have created a component which consumes the sling service from OSGI bundle in Cq5.
But while consuming it throws error stating that **com.aem.HelloService cannot be resolved to a type** , 
When looked under http://localhost:4502/system/console/services.

Service is running properly.

Comment: Please provide some code snippet, showing how you are trying to access the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your webconsole look for your OSGI bundle, this can be found for example under:

```
http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles
```

Then under your bundle's properties look for the property called **Symbolic Name**. See below for an example:
[image]

This is the path you must use in your JSP import, for example, at the top of your JSP page:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.sling.tooling.support.install%> //you might have to add .* at the end to import everything
```

Then also make sure your OSGI service Java file is properly annotated and constrcuted as per the Adobe and other documentation